# Single equation solving for unknown

Tags: polynomials

Too may years since I've done anything like this...

What I have is:
C = 589.6*Math.pow(5*R/255/((5-5*R/255)/10000),-0.1245)-162.78
usage example: given R= 132 then using above C= 22.9

Can someone please help me solve for "R" given "C".

*EDIT*
$$
C = 589.6 \left(\frac{5 R}{255((5-5 R/255)/10000}\right)^{-0.1245}-162.78
$$

Comment: What ever programming language you're using evaluates $a/b/c$ by first calculating $x=a/b$ and then $x/c$ right?

Comment: works in javascript the way i've written above

Comment: Please learn latex~

Comment: Just edited his formula and tested his number and it worked. My Question: Do you have a typical C?

Comment: Thanks for the edit... didn't know how to do that either... my apologies.

Comment: Don't understand "typical". The formula takes number R between ~50 to ~160 from a temperature sensor and converts to C in degrees celcius

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$C = 589.6 \left(\frac{5 R}{255((5-5 R/255)10000}\right)^{-0.1245}-162.78$$

Dividing the numerator and denominator of the 
fraction by $R$,
it becomes
$$C = 589.6 \left(\frac{5 }{255((5/R-5 /255)10000}\right)^{-0.1245}-162.78$$

$R$ now appears in only one place,
so you can solve for $R$
straightforwardly.

Comment: I edited his post and please note the update. Your method is still correct.

Comment: would you please show me how to solve for R "straightforwardly", sorry I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Add 162.78 to each side
Divide by 589.6
Invert (which changes the sign of the exponent on the right)
Take the log of each side
Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have it in a computer program language, you can use the method of bisection to find $R$ given $C$.

To use this, you need two values of $R$ that bracket the desired answer. Let me give you an example but google method of bisection.

Say that you want to find $R$ for $C=15$.

You know that $R=120$ gives $C=22.9$.

When $R=160$, $C=12.75$.

So you know the answer is between $120$ and $160$. Go halfway to 140.

$R=140$ gives $C=20$. This is more than 15. So answer is between 140 and 160. halfway is 150.

$R=150$ gives $C=16.4$. This is more than 15. So answer is between 150 and 160

$R=155$ gives $C=14.58$. This is less than 15. So the answer is between 150 and 155

and so on.... You can easily program your computer to find $R$ knowing $C$.
The final answer is $153.8$.